# SeDebugPrivilege token missing

Tags: winapi, privileges

I am running my application as local user administrator, but for some strange reason SeDebugPriviledge is missing from the token list of my process.

Is there any way I can add it ? (Not enabling it because it's missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx) to enable the privilege. This [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa446619.aspx) shows you how to do so.

Note that this will only be effective is your are running the process elevated.

Comment: The token does not exist I am not trying to change it to enabled / disabled

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143796/adding-not-just-enabling-sedebugprivilege same problem!

Comment: Please can you clarify the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: Man I don't have what to clarify the token is missing from the process I can't enable it because it does not exist. What is so hard to understand ?

Comment: Please stop shouting. I'm trying to help and understand. Why are you so aggressive?

Comment: Because my mother didn't loved me when I was little

Comment: So the root of the problem (other the lack of maternal love) is that you needed to run elevated. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is why I accepted the answer, could you provide a simple explanation why that happens ?

Comment: Under UAC, without elevation, your token is a restricted standard user token. It's just the UAC split token thing. All the overviews of UAC cover this.